# Плагин для вордпресса

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Подскажите пожалуйста плагин вордпресса чтобы можно было удалить сразу несколько продуктов со страницы списка желаний?

Comment: Какой плагин вы используете для списка желаний?

Comment: Я использую YITH WooCommerce Wishlist

Comment: этот функционал есть в про версии плагина, либо вы дописать его сами

Comment: Спасибо) то есть в про версии я могу выбрать несколько товаров и удалить их списка? Или сразу очистить все что есть?

Comment: можно выбрать определенные товары, можно выбрать все в один клик и удалить
у плагина есть демо страница на которой вы можете протестировать его работу

Comment: Спасибо большое